# Kendo UI grid first row always selectable and highlight

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need first row always selected default and should be highlighted.
I am using kendo UI grid. My UI code here.
 -

```
 kendo-grid="vehicleTypeGrid" k-sortable="true"
   k-data-source="vm.primaryEntityList" k-pageable='{"pageSizes":true }'
   k-selectable="true"                    
   k-columns='vm.primaryEntityGridColumns'
   k-on-change="vm.onGridRowSelectionChanged(data, dataItem, columns)"
   k-on-data-bound="vm.primaryGridDataBound(kendoEvent).
```

I tried some of the code in griddatabound event:

```
 - baseVm.prototype.primaryGridDataBound = function (e) 
  {     
  grid.element.find('tbody tr:first').addClass('k-state-selected');

};
```

This code worked for highlighted only. But I need first row always selected default and highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the grid's select() method on databound:

http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select

```
dataBound: function(e) {                          
  e.sender.select("tr:eq(1)");
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/aYEbI)**

Comment: Not working , first row is highlighted but not selected.

Comment: @donAnand, it is working! http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/aYEbI click the button I added and check the console. You will see the grid is returning the selected row. Does "selected" mean something different to you???

Comment: How to check it wil return the selected row values

Comment: See updated DOJO: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/aYEbI The button click code gets the selected row, then gets its dataitem and writes the "ShipCountry" of the selected row to a textbox.

Comment: I had to use `setTimeout` and `select(e.sender.tbody.find("tr:first"))`